# Update query doesn't update the table

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

With the following method I am trying to `update` a column named `accesstoken`. There is no exception,there is no error but the table's column doesn't get updated. What could be the reason ? Am I leaving something ?

```
public void updateAccessToken(int id , String accessToken) {

    try {
        Session session = new HVR().getSession();
        System.out.println("ID :--> " + id);
        String hql = "UPDATE UCred set accessToken ='" + accessToken + "'" + " WHERE id ='" + id + "'";
        Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
        query.executeUpdate();
        session.close();
    }catch(Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

***Note: Initially accesstoken is set to null.***

Comment: Session not set to auto commit maybe?

Comment: Indeed, I wonder if a quick fix would be just to session.flush()? If so, then configuring the session to autocommit or manually flushing is the way to go

Comment: @Ordous What is `session.commit` ? There is no method as such.

Comment: @saplingPro Edited the comment, confused it with Spring method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you manage your own transaction (i.e. not managed by containers like Spring, JTA), then you need to begin and end the transaction.

Using

```
session.getTransaction().begin();
```

and

```
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Then your code would be like this,

```
public void updateAccessToken(int id , String accessToken) {

    try {
        Session session = new HVR().getSession();

session.getTransaction().begin();
        System.out.println("ID :--> " + id);
        String hql = "UPDATE UCred set accessToken ='" + accessToken + "'" + " WHERE id ='" + id + "'";
        Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
        query.executeUpdate();

session.getTransaction().commit();

        session.close();
    }catch(Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

IS it because you're enclosing id in quotes, e.g.

> " WHERE id ='" + id + "'"

?

Comment: why do you think that too be the reason ?